# Html button with background color and image

Tags: html, css, asp.net, webforms

I'm maintaining as asp net web forms app and I'm trying to get buttons to both render an image and background color in FF, IE and Chrome. Here's what the code looks like.

With the following line only, all browsers will render the image w/o background color that I've set:

```
newButton.Style["background"] = string.Format("{1} inherit url({0}) no-repeat inherit center", imgSrc, backgroundColor);
```

The background does not color even if I add the following line:

```
newButton.Style["background-color"] = "blue";
```

If I add the '!important' directive to the above line then IE and Chrome render a background color. FF still shows 'background-color: transparent' and 'background: url(...) transparent'

What am I missing here?

Comment: Just a quick watch, Run your page in FF browser and open Inspect element tab. Then click on Html on Left pane and you will find style on right pane. Just find newButton tag using search dom element. and have a quick view on style pane. If you find don't **background-color:blue !important** in element.style then your dynamic css hasn't rendered in FF.

Comment: yes, 'background-color:transparent' AND 'background: url(...) transparent' appear instead of blue.